# tuple to list conversion within dictionary values (list of lists (and tuples))

Tags: python

I am dealing with a dictionary that is formatted as such:

```
dic = {'Start': [['Story' , '.']], 
       'Wonderful': [('thing1',), ["thing1", "and", "thing2"]], 
       'Amazing': [["The", "thing", "action", "the", "thing"]], 
       'Fantastic': [['loved'], ['ate'], ['messaged']], 
       'Example': [['bus'], ['car'], ['truck'], ['pickup']]}
```

if you notice, in the story key, there is a tuple within a list.  I am looking for a way to convert all tuples within the inner lists of each key into lists.

I have tried the following:

```
for value in dic.values():
    for inner in value:
       inner = list(inner)
```

but that does not work and I don't see why.  I also tried an if type(inner) = tuple statement to try and convert it only if its a tuple but that is not working either...  Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

edit:  I am not allowed to import, and only have really learned a basic level of python.  A solution that I could understand with that in mind is preferred.

Comment: Parenthesis do not make tuples, commas do. `('Phrase', )` is a tuple, `('Phrase')` is a string with unneeded parenthesis. As a result `list(('Phrase'))` will give you a list of characters, while `list(('Phrase', ))` will give you a list with a single string.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? What is the result you are getting and what is the expected result?

Comment: @mark:  Oops, sorry i forgot to add the comma.  I was aware of this fact, but thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @sembeiNormaki:  I am trying to make every everything in the dictionary a list of lists.

Comment: How about not producing that undesired data in the first place, instead producing the desired data right away?

Comment: Don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to invest some time learning how [assignment in Python works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns).

`inner = list(inner)` constructs a list (right hand side), then binds the name `inner` to that new list and then... you do nothing with it.

Fixing your code:

```
for k, vs in dic.items():
    dic[k] = [list(x) if isinstance(x, tuple) else x for x in vs]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the element by its index

```
for curr in dic.values():
    for i, v in enumerate(curr):
        if isinstance(v, tuple):
            curr[i] = list(v)

print(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title, data and code suggest that you only have tuples and lists there and are willing to run `list()` on all of them, so here's a short way to convert them all to lists **and assign them back into the outer lists** (which is what you were missing) ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDBasQgFLz7FQ8vLwHZSy9F6C@UQpdeJAezcTfSVMPTLYTSb0@fmpZ6mTfzZgZ13fIcw8PjSvs@@Qs8wRe@ZksZNRjDY6QNQQGecBgYmsC7Dl9mssmh6hUY2YhUIG2YCqRilDVzGEuhPM/V9BzvoeCbo7Fg/ifXTFm0K4w@IysGLzO3TG1@96nOxVpCzXrztLT9GLcjZI/0FG9s/xZiJR9yh6O7RnIaFfCzeyGYwadd7g58KNKpktT1WgCfyowe@IM@7NotPmXVxP6v0l6zIw2/lfv@Aw)):

```
for value in dic.values():
    value[:] = map(list, value)
```

And a fun way ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/NSsQwEL73KYZcppWwFy9S8BVEULyEHtJtdhtckzJJhSI@e51JqjiXb@b7mUmWLc8x3D8stO@TP8MjfOFLtpSxB2O4jbQhaMATDgNDJVhr8XkmmxzqToNRdVAalA2TQBKjKpnDKAvV61xMT3ENgm@ORsH8jy4ZEeoTRp@RGYPnmbdMtX/3qfRilVC1Xj3dqj7G7QjZIz3FK9u/m2YhH3KLo7tEcj1q4G93TcMTfNrb6sAHoU5lSG3XN8Alsuc9d4U2fhjE58L64chm1xb68EotNqW/W/aSHfXwe2vffwA)):

```
for value in dic.values():
    for i, [*value[i]] in enumerate(value):
        pass
```